# Not able to set cookie samesite=none for spring boot 1.5.22

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, samesite

I working on spring boot 1.5.22 and i'm facing an issue with the cookies samesite=none proporty.I'm not able to set the samesite attribute for cookies because of which the oauth authentication is not working on chrome but it is working on other browser. So, I tried few solutions like this.

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class.cast(container);
            factory.addContextCustomizers(new TomcatContextCustomizer() {
                @Override
                void customize(Context context) {
                    Rfc6265CookieProcessor cookieProcessor = new Rfc6265CookieProcessor()
                    cookieProcessor.setSameSiteCookies("None")
                    context.setCookieProcessor(cookieProcessor)
                }

            })
        }
    }
}
```

And that didn't help.So i tried adding a custom filter

```
@Component
public class SameSiteFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        addSameSiteCookieAttribute((HttpServletResponse) response);
    }

    private void addSameSiteCookieAttribute(HttpServletResponse response) {
        Collection<String> headers = response.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);
        boolean firstHeader = true;
        for (String header : headers)
 {

            if (firstHeader) {
                response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, String.format("%s; %s", header, "SameSite=None;"));
                firstHeader = false;
                continue;
            }
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, String.format("%s; %s", header, "SameSite=None;"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

I added this as addFilterBefore(new SameSiteFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class) and addFilterAfter(new SameSiteFilter(),BasicAuthencticationFilter.class)
in HttpSecurity configure

Anyway to set the SameSite=None for jsessionid

Answer (score 1):

i was using embedded tomcat 8.54 which was not setting samesite to none but working for other values like lax,strict. So updated embedded the tomcat to 8.58 in which i guess they fixed that bug. So, updating tomcat version solved my problem

Comment: Bro, can you provide the full project or upated code for this? I have the same exact issue!